# Eclipse prompts to download servlet from localhost

Tags: java, servlets

I've been getting propmted to download the servlet that is running (CmdServlet) from the local host every time I run it and change the url to 
http:// localhost:8080/CommandWeb/CmdServlet?cmd=weather&loc=12780913
I'm using Tomcat6

the CmdServlet

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import Command.Command;
import Command.WeatherCommand;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CmdServlet
 */
public class CmdServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private HashMap<String, Command> commands;
    private String error = "error.jsp";
    private String jspdir = "/";



public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    initCommands();
}

private void initCommands() {
    commands = new HashMap<String, Command>();
    commands.put("weather",new WeatherCommand());

}

public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String next = "";

    try{
        Command cmd = lookupCommand(request.getParameter("cmd"));
        cmd.execute(request,response);
        System.out.println("CmdServlet:cmd = " + cmd + ", zip = " + next);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Command lookupCommand(String key) {
    return commands.get(key);
}
```

the WeatherCommand

```
package Command;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



/**
 * Servlet implementation class WeatherCommand
 */
public class WeatherCommand extends HttpServlet implements Command{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public WeatherCommand() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("test/html");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

    String zip = request.getParameter("loc");
    System.out.println(zip);
    WeatherWrapper w = null;
    try {
        w = Weather.getWeather(zip);
        pw.println(w.getCondition());
    } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        response.sendError(0,"Not A Location");
    }
    pw.close();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    doGet(request,response);
    return "";
}

    }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-    app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>CommandWeb</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>Command.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>CmdServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>CmdServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>controller.CmdServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>CmdServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/CmdServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>WeatherCommand</display-name>
<servlet-name>WeatherCommand</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Command.WeatherCommand</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>WeatherCommand</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/WeatherCommand</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: would be helpful if you provide your deployment descriptor ( ex. web.xml) details

Comment: @user1352127 that won't help in this case.

Comment: Have you debugged this in order to check how the application behaves when processing the `GET` request?

Comment: Yea but I keep getting weird results. When I start the debug and change the URL I get prompt, I would hit cancel and the URL would be unchanged. I would change the URL again and then it would debug all the way through. Also its not out putting to the page even when I go over where its printing to the response writer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are sending a "non-standard" `content-type` header on your `doGet()` method. As the browser does not recognize it, it will consider a binary type and prompt the user to download.

Change your response content type.

From:

```
response.setContentType("test/html");
```

To:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

Comment: Hey, look on the bright side, at least the solution is easy :)

Comment: It works but I still get prompted the first time I run it and change the URL. I try again and then it works

Comment: It happens, possibly some cache going on there. Try opening a new tab/window or force reload through CTRL+F5. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using the internal browser in eclipse, but when I switched it to chrome it works fine?

Comment: Yeah, just so you can debug this in the future, in Chrome, press F12, it will open Chrome's Developer Tools, get to tab `Network`, there you can see the HTTP request sent and response received. You can see the `content-type` headers as well - and much more.